# Return last element of listView and set it into text view - falls on NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, textview

Please help me with little thing that make me crazy

I’m trying to set text in a textview that is the last element of a dynamic Array.

I add a function inside my Adapter that return the last element of the array.

I’m coming back to the Main Activity where I’d like to show the text and during time it falls at “nullpointerexception”.

Please help

Here is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private static Context mContext;

    public Button mExit, mHistory, mRating;

    public  TextView mSignal;

    HistoryAdapt myLastItem;

    List<HistoryItems> m_myLastItem;



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainActivity.mContext=getApplicationContext();

        mExit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ExitButton);
        mExit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mHistory=(Button)findViewById(R.id.HistoryButton);
        mHistory.setOnClickListener(this);

        mRating=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RateButton);
        mRating.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSignal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SignalOfTheDayTV);

        //### SET LAST ELEMENT INTO TEXTVIEW

         m_myLastItem = new ArrayList<HistoryItems>();

        myLastItem=new HistoryAdapt(mContext,  m_myLastItem );



        m_myLastItem= (List<HistoryItems>) myLastItem.getLastElement();


        mSignal.setText(( (HistoryItems) m_myLastItem).getTitle());



    //  AppRater.app_launched(this);

        //  AppRater.showRateDialog(this, null);

        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
        ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(AppManager.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    }//oncreate



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static Context getAppContext(){
        return MainActivity.mContext;
    }


    public void ExitState(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("You're about to quit Signals4Trading");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.five);
        //builder.setMessage("Your device has been registered successfully. You'll receive signals very soon.");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);//can't click on the background of the activity
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"See you soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                finish();


            }//OnClickListener PositiveButton
        });//anonymous class PositiveButton
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enjoy your visit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog  = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }//ExitState

    public void goToHistoryActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryAct.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void rateApp(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Rate.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.ExitButton:
            ExitState();
            break;          

        case R.id.HistoryButton:
            goToHistoryActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.RateButton:
            rateApp();
            break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        //Stop the analytics tracking
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }

}//MainActivity



**Adapter:**

    package com.Signals4Trading.push.android;

import java.util.List;





import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HistoryAdapt extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<HistoryItems>items;
    private final Context context;

    public HistoryAdapt(Context context,List<HistoryItems>items){
        this.context=context;
        this.items=items;

    }//constructor

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id;
    }


 //###FUNCTION THAT RETURN LAST ELEMENT

    public HistoryItems getLastElement(){

        HistoryItems lastItem = items.get(items.size());

        if(items!=null && !items.isEmpty()){
             lastItem = items.get(items.size()-1);
        }

          return lastItem;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.historyitems, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitleTV);
            holder.itemDate=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDateTV);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


         holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.itemDate.setText(items.get(position).getDate());


        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTitle;
        TextView itemDate;
    }

}
//HistoryAdapt
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error because you have never intialized the object of your adapter class

```
  HistoryAdapt in requires a context and and list to pass into it ,as defined in your constructor
```

Comment: Ok, so I understand that in my MainActivity, I have to add : HistoryAdapt myLastItem=new HistoryAdapt(getApplicationContext(),  ???? ); What sould I write instead of "???"

Comment: nope you have to initialize it appropriately pass the context and a list which contains the objects of  HistoryItems

Comment: you should write a list which contains the objects of HistoryItems instead of ????

Comment: Something like this : HistoryAdapt myLastItem;
 
 List<HistoryItems> m_myLastItem; ..... Oncreate(){myLastItem=new HistoryAdapt(mContext,  m_myLastItem );
  
  m_myLastItem= (List<HistoryItems>) myLastItem.getLastElement();
  
    
  mSignal.setText(((Activity) m_myLastItem).getTitle());
  }

Comment: yup but add proper values to the HistoryItems objets you add into the list or it can produce nullpointerexception and upvote the answer if it helped

Comment: which proper value? Those 2 last lines are very confusing to me : m_myLastItem= (List<HistoryItems>) myLastItem.getLastElement();
  
    
  mSignal.setText(((Activity) m_myLastItem).getTitle());

Comment: whatever values your HistoryItems class contains and you are using it in adapter

Comment: ok, i edit my code and made a few changes so you can see what i am initializing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because Listitems is still referencing to null object. Have you called HistoryAdapt(context,items) constructor before calling

HistoryItems l_myLastItem= (HistoryItems) myLastItem.getLastElement(0); 
?

Comment: Hi did something like that but it seems odd: Something like this : HistoryAdapt myLastItem;
 
 List<HistoryItems> m_myLastItem; ..... Oncreate(){myLastItem=new HistoryAdapt(mContext,  m_myLastItem );
  
  m_myLastItem= (List<HistoryItems>) myLastItem.getLastElement();
  
    
  mSignal.setText(((Activity) m_myLastItem).getTitle());
  }

Comment: you have declared the m_myLastItem member but you haven't initialize that.

Comment: @user3111349 where did you initializes HistoryAdapt? He is saying that you need to initialize before calling any method of HistoryAdapt.

Comment: ok, i edit my code and made a few changes so you can see what i am initializing.

Comment: When you are calling myLastItem=new HistoryAdapt(mContext,  m_myLastItem ); m_myLastItem reference to null object, so before calling this statement write m_myLastItem = new ArrayList<HistoryItems>(); and put some data into the list if you want. And in getLastElement() method check whether list is referencing to null or not and also check for empty list using if(items!=null && !items.isEmpty()){ }

Comment: This was a very clear answer, many thanks! I edit my code so you can see the changes I made. Anyway, it falls on Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1

Comment: can you provide the logcat ? where it actually fails (line number) ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Signals4Trading.push.android.HistoryItems cannot be cast to java.util.List
11-11 14:52:14.802: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):  at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
11-11 14:52:14.802: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-11 14:52:14.802: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-11 14:52:14.802: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)

Answer (score 1):

Do as Haresh Chhelana said

```
public HistoryItems getLastElement(){
    return items.get(items.size()-1); 
}
```

the reason you are getting null pointer exception is because your list has not been initialized so it is referencing null. To get rid of this error you should first initialize your ArrayList then populate it as

```
//### SET LAST ELEMENT INTO TEXTVIEW
m_myListItem = new ArrayList(); 
//then add some data to arrayList for eg:
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
    m_myListItem.add(new HistoryItem().setTitle("title " + i));
}
myLastItem=new HistoryAdapt(mContext,  m_myListItem ); //this should be m_myListItem not m_myLastItem

m_myLastItem= myLastItem.getLastElement();// m_myLastItem should be of type HistoryItem as HistoryItem m_myLastItem not List<HistoryItems> m_myLastItem


mSignal.setText(m_myLastItem.getTitle());
```

P.S. please have a look at your variable naming convention

Comment: Well Thank you but the function add() in m_myListItem.add(new HistoryItem().setTitle("title " + i)); is not applicable for the argument void. What should I do with this function?

Comment: and it also falls on : Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Signals4Trading.push.android.HistoryItems cannot be cast to java.util.List
11-11 14:52:14.802: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):  at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
11-11 14:52:14.802: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-11 14:52:14.802:

Comment: sorry i just copied and paste your code and forgot to remove cast now it should work

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work.. Please somebody can help me. I am very confused with those changes because when I insert them inside my code. It doesn't fit at all. They ask me for lot of different casting and nothing work. I'm trying for like 1 hour..

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass last item index instead directly get index from adapter list size.

```
public HistoryItems getLastElement(){
    return items.get(items.size()-1); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it but it falls again on the same nullpointerexception